# how can i update current object in parse.com with javascript?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I want to update object i already have in parse.com with javascript; what i did is i retirevied the object first with query but i dont know how to update it.

here is the code i use, whats wrong on it?

```
var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("Driver");
var query = new Parse.Query(GameScore);
query.equalTo("DriverID", "9");
query.find({
  success: function(results) {

    alert("Successfully retrieved " + results.length + "DName");

     results.set("DName", "aaaa");
    results.save();
  },
  error: function(error) {
    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
  }
});
```

Comment: looks fine according to the [documentation](https://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Object.html#set), what is the actual problem you are having?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found the solution, incase someone needs it later

here it is:

```
var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("Driver");
var query = new Parse.Query(GameScore);
query.equalTo("DriverID", "9");
query.first({
  success: function(object) {

     object.set("DName", "aaaa");
    object.save();


  },
  error: function(error) {
    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
  }
});
```

Comment: The difference between the question and your answer may not be obvious at first- So for everyone who has happened here- Use query.first instead of query.find. Find returns an array of objects, and the array has no method "set" or "save". First returns a single backbone style object which has those methods available.

Comment: how can i do both save or update in one function. Set is for only update the rows. If row is not exist how to save inside the find function

Comment: I'm able to retrive my values using objectId , but on success i try to set a new value , but always i get "{"code":101,"error":"object not found for update"}" error , please help me . Thanks In advance :)

Answer (score 22):

The difference between the question and your answer may not be obvious at first- So for everyone who has happened here- Use **query.first** instead of **query.find**.

```
query.find()  //don't use this if you are going to try and update an object
```

returns an array of objects, an array which has no method "set" or "save".

```
query.first() //use this instead
```

returns a single backbone style object which has those methods available.

Answer (score 3):

If someone got msg "{"code":101,"error":"object not found for update"}", check the class permission and ACL of Object to enrure it's allowed to read and write

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:

```
var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("Driver");
var query = new Parse.Query(GameScore);
query.equalTo("DriverID", "9");
query.find({
  success: function(results) {

   alert("Successfully retrieved " + results.length + "DName");
      // - use this-----------------
      results.forEach((result) => {
        result.set("DName", "aaaa");
      });
      Parse.Object.saveAll(results);
      // --------------------------------
 },
 error: function(error) {
   alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
 var results= await query.find();
          for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
          results[i].set("DName", "aaaa");
          results[i].save();
          }
```