# Parse.com Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of undefined JavaScript

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

After having manually created a record within an object named "Cards" in parse.com with an objectId  of 9e9JAIYSFa, I am attempting to retrieve attributes (attack and defense) of this record by closely following the documentation.

```
alert("1");
var Cards = Parse.Object.extend("Cards");
alert("2");
var cards = new Cards();
alert("3");
var query = new Parse.Query(cards);
alert("4");
query.get("9e9JAIYSFa", {
    success: function (cards) {
        alert("5");
    },
    error: function (object, error) {
        alert("6")
    }
});
alert("7")

    var attack = cards.get("attack");
    var defense = cards.get("defense");
alert("8");
    alert(attack);
    alert(defense);
alert("9");
```

This returns the error in chrome:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of undefined
```

which is pointing to line 3 of the parse-1.3.2.min.js file.

A point worth noting is that only alerts 1, 2 and 3 are displayed.

After looking at these questions:

[Parse - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26092517/parse-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-get-of-undefined)

[Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined - How do I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24199942/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-get-of-undefined-how-do-i-solve-thi)

[how can i update current object in parse.com with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13251955/how-can-i-update-current-object-in-parse-com-with-javascript)

I tried accessing the objectId manually using this code:

```
    query.equalTo("objectId", "9e9JAIYSFa");
    query.find({
        success: function (cards) {
            alert("Working");
        },
        error: function (object, error) {
            alert("Not working");
        }
    });
```

But this also results in the same error.

Any ideas?

Comment: var query = new Parse.Query(`cards`); shoud be `Cards`

Comment: Thank you. If you create an answer with this information then I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters of Parse.Query should be class rather class instance. -- ref. [Parse.Query](https://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Query.html#constructor)

It should fix the problem by replacing `cards` from `var query = new Parse.Query(cards);` to `Cards` as `var query = new Parse.Query(Cards);`.